# Get contagion chain from adjacency matrix, r, igraph

Tags: r, matrix, igraph, adjacency-list

Q.I have a erdos.reyni graph. I infect a vertex and want to see what sequence of vertices the disease would follow? igraph has helful functions like get.adjacency(), neighbors().

Details. This is the adjacency matrix with vertex names instead of 0,1 flags and i'm trying to get the contagion chain out of it. Like the flow/sequence of an epidemic through a graph if a certain vertex is infected. Let's not worry about infection probabilities here (assume all vertices hit are infected with probability 1).

So suppose I hit vertex 1 (which is row 1 here). We see that it has outgoing links to vertex 4,5,18,22,23,24,25. So then the next vertices will be those connected to 4,5,18...25 i.e. those values in row4, row5, row18,... row25. Then, according to the model, the disease will travel through these and so forth.

I understand that I can pass a string to order the matrix rows. My problem is, I cannot figure out how to generate that sequence.

The matrix looks like this.

```
    > channel
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 [1,]    4    5   18   22   23   24   25   NA
 [2,]    6   10   11   18   25   NA   NA   NA
 [3,]    7   11   18   20   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [4,]   24   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [5,]    1    3    9   13   14   NA   NA   NA
 [6,]    3    8    9   14   19   23   NA   NA
 [7,]    3    4    8   15   20   22   NA   NA
 [8,]    2    3   25   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [9,]    3    4   11   13   20   NA   NA   NA
[10,]    4    5    8   15   19   20   21   22
[11,]    3   13   15   18   19   23   NA   NA
[12,]   11   13   16   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[13,]    4    6   14   15   16   17   19   21
[14,]    2    6   13   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[15,]    3   17   20   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[16,]    6   15   18   23   NA   NA   NA   NA
[17,]    2   25   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[18,]    2    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[19,]    3   11   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[20,]    1    4    7   10   12   21   22   25
[21,]    2    4    6   13   14   16   18   NA
[22,]    1    3    4   15   23   NA   NA   NA
[23,]    1   16   24   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[24,]    7    8   19   20   22   NA   NA   NA
[25,]    7   12   13   17   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

I want to reorder this matrix based on a selection criteria as follows:

R would be most helpful (but i'm interested in the algo so any python,ruby,etc.will be great).The resulting vector will have length of 115 (8x25=200 - 85 NAs=115). and would look like this. Which is basically how the disease would spread if vertex 1, becomes infected.

```
4,5,18,22,23,24,25,24,1,3,9,13,14,2,5,1,3,4,15,23,1,16,24,7,8,19,20,22,7,12,13,17,7,8,19,20,22, 4,5,18,22,23,24,25,7,11,18,20...
```

What I know so far:
 1. R has a package `**igraph**` which lets me calculate neighbors`(graph, vertex, "out")`
 2. The same package can also generate `get.adjlist(graph...), get.adjacency`

Comment: interesting comments. Now that you guys insist. This matrix is the adjacency matrix with vector names instead of the binary flags.
The output would be the epidemic flow model.. except that it is not modeling a disease but rather a bank default!! :)

As for the hint... well from the last 2 weeks of coding i gathered that with high level languages like R/java, it was much better manipulating vectors than the old school char types in C++.

Comment: Wait, isn't this basically a breadth-first search through the graph?

Comment: Have a look at `graph.bfs()`, specifically the `order` argument.

Comment: @Marius yes.. that's exactly what i'm trying to achieve! Except since this is not a erdos.reyni directoinal graph the breadth-first will lead to an infinite sequence.. i just want to know how to get the fist  few. will look at graph.bfs()

Comment: Breadth-first search works on undirected graphs because you mantain a list of the nodes you've visited, it doesn't end up infinite, it just gets to all reachable nodes.

Comment: @Marius U're the man! It is exactly what i was looking for! Thnx

Comment: @jordan certainly it is the same problem. But not the same question necessarily. That one (before the edits) was about ordering matrix regardless of context or language. This is about graph theory and breadth first-search.

I tried deleting the dupe but needed more votes. On second thoughts we can leave that for pedantics looking to sort matrices in an irregular way. The solution would be sorting matrices and not use a pre-def fucntion. I found no sorting algo anywhere for such problem. Thnx for the help guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finding a "contagion chain" like this is equivalent to a breadth-first search through the graph, e.g.:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(50)
g = erdos.renyi.game(20, 0.1)
plot(g)
order = graph.bfs(g, root=14, order=TRUE, unreachable=FALSE)$order
```

Output:

```
> order
 [1]  14   1   2  11  16  18   4  19  12  17  20   7   8  15   5  13   9 NaN NaN NaN
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you define the ordering of the rows, so... just a few hints:

You can select a permutation/combination of rows by passing an index vector:

```
> (m <- matrix(data=1:9, nrow=3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> m[c(2,3,1),]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5    8
[2,]    3    6    9
[3,]    1    4    7
```

The function `t()` transposes a matrix.

The matrix is stored in columns-first (or [column-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-major_order#Column-major_order)) order:

```
> as.vector(m)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

`NA` values can be removed by subsetting:

```
> qq <- c(1,2,NA,5,7,NA,3,NA,NA)
> qq[!is.na(qq)]
[1] 1 2 5 7 3
```

Also, graph algorithms are provided by Bioconductor's [graph](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.11/bioc/html/graph.html) or CRAN's [igraph](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/index.html) packages.